# Comparing 2 Huge csv Files in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 csv files.

**File1:**

```
EmployeeName,Age,Salary,Address
Vinoth,12,2548.245,"140,North Street,India"
Vinoth,12,2548.245,"140,North Street,India"
Karthick,10,10.245,"140,North Street,India"
```

**File2:**

```
EmployeeName,Age,Salary,Address
Karthick,10,10.245,"140,North Street,India"
Vivek,20,2000,"USA"
Vinoth,12,2548.245,"140,North Street,India"
```

I want to compare these 2 files and report the differences into another csv file. I've used the below python code ( version 2.7)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import difflib
import csv

with open('./Input/file1', 'r' ) as t1:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
with open('./Input/file2', 'r' ) as t2:
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)

    for line in fileone:
        if line not in filetwo:
            outFile.write(line)
```

When I execute, below is the output I got:

**Actual Output**

```
Vivek,20,2000,"USA"
```

But my expected output is below since the Records for "Vinoth" in file1 is present 2 times, but only present 1 time in file2.

**Expected Output**

```
Vinoth,12,2548.245,"140,North Street,India"
Vivek,20,2000,"USA"
```

**Questions**

1. Please let me know how to get the expected output.
2. Also , how to get the Filename and line number of the difference record to the output file?

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Is it huge files as in large than available memory? 2) How many GB of data in each file?

Comment: I don't understand your criteria. If Karthick is not present in your new file, why Vinoth should be? Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás `Karthick` is found once in the two files, while there's only one `Vinoth` line in _file2_ and two in _file1_. He also wants to consider the number of time a line appears.

Comment: @FredrikHedman Yes, the files are huge. Approximately, it's 3.5 GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that the `in` keyword only checks for the presence of an item, not if the item exists twice.  If you are open to using an external package, you can do this pretty quickly with pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('Input/file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Input/file2.csv')

# create a new column with the count of how many times the row exists
df1['count'] = 0
df2['count'] = 0
df1['count'] = df1.groupby(df1.columns.to_list()[:-1]).cumcount() + 1
df2['count'] = df2.groupby(df2.columns.to_list()[:-1]).cumcount() + 1

# merge the two data frames with and outer join, add an indicator variable
# to show where each row (including the count) exists.
df_all = df1.merge(df2, on=df1.columns.to_list(), how='outer', indicator='exists')
print(df_all)
# prints:
  EmployeeName  Age    Salary                 Address  count      exists
0       Vinoth   12  2548.245  140,North Street,India      1        both
1       Vinoth   12  2548.245  140,North Street,India      2   left_only
2     Karthick   10    10.245  140,North Street,India      1        both
3        Vivek   20  2000.000                     USA      1  right_only

# clean up exists column and export the rows do not exist in both frames
df_all['exists'] = (df_all.exists.str.replace('left_only', 'file1')
                                 .str.replace('right_only', 'file2'))
df_all.query('exists != "both"').to_csv('update.csv', index=False)
```

#### Edit: non-pandas version

You can check for difference in **identical** line counts using the row as a key and the count as the value.

```py
from collection import defaultdict

c1 = defaultdict(int)
c2 = defaultdict(int)

with open('./Input/file1', 'r' ) as t1:
    for line in t1:
        c1[line.strip()] += 1

with open('./Input/file2', 'r' ) as t2:
    for line in t2:
        c2[line.strip()] += 1

# create a set of all rows
all_keys = set()
all_keys.update(c1)
all_keys.update(c2)

# find the difference in the number of instances of the row
out = []
for k in all_keys:
    diff = c1[k] - c2[k]
    if diff == 0:
        continue
    if diff > 0:
        out.extend([k + ',file1'] * diff) # add which file it came from
    if diff < 0:
        out.extend([k + ',file2'] * abs(diff)) # add which file it came from

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write('\n'.join(out))
```

Comment: We do not have pandas Module, Is there any way to do without using external package

Comment: Sure, see the updated answer.  The `collections` module is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

use panda compare

```
import pandas as pd

f1 = pd.read_csv(file_1.csv)
f2 = pd.read_csv(file_2.csv)

changed = f1.compare(f2)
change = f1[f1.index.isin(changed.index)]   
print(change)
```